# Как использовать виджет DynamicForm для Yii2

Tags: yii2, form, виджет, dynamic

У меня возник вопрос. У меня есть 2 таблицы в бд. В первой таблице TABLE_SITY у меня содержаться данные о городах. Во второй таблице TABLE_STREETS у меня содержаться данные об улицах. При добавлении нового города или при редактировании существующего города мне нужно сделать добавление/удаление улиц к нему и сохранение этого в бд. Через инструмент GII я сгенерировал модели к этим таблицам. И через инструмент CRUD сгенерировал к таблице TABLE_SITY контроллер и представления. Для решение данной проблемы я нашел [данный виджет](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform), который сможет решить эти проблемы. Стал реализовывать все на [примере из документации](https://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo1/source-code). Но на выходе я получаю ошибку: Attribute name must contain word characters only. Что не так?

**Код контроллера:**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new TableSity();
        $modelTs = [new TableStreets];

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $modelTs = Model::createMultiple(TableStreets::className());
            Model::loadMultiple($modelTs, Yii::$app->request->post());

            // Ajax validation
//            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
//                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
//                return ArrayHelper::merge(
//                    ActiveForm::validateMultiple($modelTs),
//                    ActiveForm::validate($model)
//                );
//            }

            // Validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelTs) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        foreach ($modelTs as $modelTs) {
                            $modelTs->ID_SITY = $model->ID;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelTs->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
//                'modelTs' => $modelTs,
                'modelTs' => (empty($modelTs)) ? [new TableStreets] : $modelTs,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**Код create.php:**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\TableSity */

$this->title = 'Добавление нового Города';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Список городов', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>

<div class="tablesity-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelTs' => $modelTs,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

**Код формы:**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;

$js = ' jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
            jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index) {
                jQuery(this).html("Address: " + (index + 1))
            });
        });

        jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
            jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index) {
                jQuery(this).html("Address: " + (index + 1))
            });
        }); ';

$this->registerJs($js);

?>

<div class="tablesity-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'NAME_SITY')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'DESC_SITY')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic'
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'LIST_ATTRAC')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic'
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'RAND')->checkbox() ?>

    <!-- Добавление начато -->
    <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
        'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper',
        'widgetBody' => '.container-items',
        'widgetItem' => '.item',
        'limit' => 4,
        'min' => 0,
        'insertButton' => '.add-item',
        'deleteButton' => '.remove-item',
        'model' => $modelTs[0],
        'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
        'formFields' => [
            'NAME_ANSWER',
            'TEXT_ANSWER',
            'CORR_ANSWER',
            'STATUS ',
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Address Book
            <button type="button" class="pull-right add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add address</button>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
            <?php foreach ($modelTs as $index => $modelTs): ?>

                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->

                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <span class="panel-title-address">Address: <?= ($index + 1) ?></span>
                        <button type="button" class="pull-right remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                        // necessary for update action.
                        if (!$modelTs->isNewRecord) {
                            echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelTs, "[{$index}]id");
                        }
                        ?>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelTs, "[{$index}]NAME_ANSWER")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelTs, "[{$index}]TEXT_ANSWER")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- end:row -->

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelTs, "[{$index}]CORR_ANSWER")->checkbox() ?>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- end:row -->
                    </div>

                </div>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
    <!-- Добавление окончено -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Добавить' : 'Применить изменения', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вот как все заработало.

**Код контроллера:**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new SQuizQuestion();
        $modelsQa = [new SQuizQA];
        // Сохраняем вопрос
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            $modelsQa = Model::createMultiple(SQuizQA::classname());
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsQa, Yii::$app->request->post());

            // Validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsQa) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        foreach ($modelsQa as $modelQa) {
                            $modelQa->ID_QUESTION = $model->ID_REC;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelQa->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID_REC]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsQa' => (empty($modelsQa)) ? [new SQuizQA] : $modelsQa,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {

        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $modelsQa = $model->sQUIZQAs;
        //print_r($modelsQa);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            $oldIDsAnswers = ArrayHelper::map($modelsQa, 'ID_REC', 'ID_REC');
            $modelsQa = Model::createMultiple(SQuizQA::classname(), $modelsQa);
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsQa, Yii::$app->request->post());
            $deletedIDsAnswers = array_diff($oldIDsAnswers, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsQa, 'ID_REC', 'ID_REC')));

            // Validate all models
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsQa) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        if (!empty($deletedIDsAnswers)) {
                            SQuizQA::deleteAll(['ID_REC' => $deletedIDsAnswers]);
                        }
                        foreach ($modelsQa as $modelQa) {
                            $modelQa->ID_QUESTION = $model->ID_REC;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelQa->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID_REC]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }

        } else {
            $topics_id_arr = $model->getTopic()
                ->select(['ID_REC'])
                ->column();
            foreach($topics_id_arr as $ID_REC){
                $model->topics_id_arr[$ID_REC] = ['selected' => 'selected'];
            }
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelsQa' => (empty($modelsQa)) ? [new SQuizQA] : $modelsQa,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**Код create.php и update.php**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model common\models\references\SQUIZQUESTION */

$this->title = 'Добавление нового вопроса';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Список вопросов', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>

<div class="squizquestion-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsQa' => $modelsQa,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

**Код формы:**

```
<?php

use common\models\references\SQuizTopic;

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;

$js = ' jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
            jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-answer").each(function(i) {
                jQuery(this).html("Ответ: " + (i + 1))
            });
        });

        jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
            jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-answer").each(function(i) {
                jQuery(this).html("Ответ: " + (i + 1))
            });
        });
        ';

$this->registerJs($js);

?>

<div class="squizquestion-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'NAME_QUEST')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'TEXT_QUEST')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic'
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'MSG_QUEST')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic'
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'RANDOM')->checkbox() ?>

    <!-- Добавление начато -->
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4> Ответы на вопрос</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper',
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items',
                'widgetItem' => '.item',
                'limit' => 20,
                'min' => 1,
                'insertButton' => '.add-item',
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item',
                'model' => $modelsQa[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    'NAME_ANSWER',
                    'TEXT_ANSWER',
                    'CORR_ANSWER',
                    'STATUS',
                ],
            ]); ?>
            <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->

                <?php foreach ($modelsQa as $i => $modelQa): ?>
                    <div class="item panel panel-default panel-primary"><!-- widgetBody -->
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h5 class="panel-title-answer pull-left">Ответ: <?= ($i + 1) ?></h5>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modelQa->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelQa, "[{$i}]ID_REC");
                            }
                            ?>

                            <?= $form->field($modelQa, "[{$i}]NAME_ANSWER")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

                            <?= $form->field($modelQa, "[{$i}]TEXT_ANSWER")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

                            <?= $form->field($modelQa, "[{$i}]CORR_ANSWER")->checkbox() ?>

                            <?= $form->field($modelQa, "[{$i}]STATUS")->checkbox() ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
            <!-- Добавление окончено -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Добавить' : 'Изменить', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```